# php multidimensional array unique with different value make key value array

Tags: php, arrays

i need help for Below Array:

```
$inputarray = array(
    array("id" => 2,"name" => "ProductName","comment" => "best product comment 1"),
    array("id" => 2,"name" => "ProductName","comment" => "best product comment 2"),
    array("id" => 2,"name" => "ProductName","comment" => "best product comment 3")
);
```

output should be:

```
$outputarray = array(
    array("id" => 2,"name" => "ProductName","comment" => array("best product comment 1","best product comment 2","best product comment 3"))
);
```

i need this "comment" key of value array in return

```
array_unique
```

is not working in it.
it gives me unique but not that comments array. it's only give me last value of comment key value 
like below

```
$outputarray = array(
    array("id" => 2,"name" => "ProductName","comment" => "best product comment 3")
);
```

please help me out.

Comment: Is your `$inputarray` contains multiple products or just single??

Comment: yes it's multiple products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [`array_reduce`](http://www.php.net/array_reduce):

```
<?php
$input_array = [
  ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'ProductName', 'comment' => 'best product comment 1'],
  ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'ProductName', 'comment' => 'best product comment 2'],
  ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'ProductName', 'comment' => 'best product comment 3'],
  ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'ProductName2', 'comment' => 'best product comment 4'],
  ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'ProductName2', 'comment' => 'best product comment 5']
];

$output_array = array_values(array_reduce($input_array, function($output_array, $item) {
  if (array_key_exists($item['id'], $output_array)) {
    $output_array[$item['id']]['comment'][] = $item['comment'];
  }
  else {
    $item['comment'] = (array)$item['comment'];
    $output_array[$item['id']] = $item;
  }
  return $output_array;
}, []));

echo '<pre>'; var_dump($output_array); echo '</pre>';
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/QfGYF)

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if this is what you've ment but here is how you can group the product comments.

```
$inputarray = array(
array("id" => 2,"name" => "ProductName","comment" => "best product comment 1"),
array("id" => 2,"name" => "ProductName","comment" => "best product comment 2"),
array("id" => 2,"name" => "ProductName","comment" => "best product comment 3")
);
$outputarray = [];
$tmp_comments = [];
foreach ($inputarray as $arrays) {
  $tmp_comments[$arrays['id']][] = $arrays['comment'];
  $outputarray[$arrays['id']] = array('id' => $arrays['id'], 'name' => $arrays['name']); 
}

foreach ($tmp_comments as $id => $comments) {
  $outputarray[$id]['comment'] = $comments;
}

print_r($outputarray);
```

outputs

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => ProductName
            [comment] => Array
                (
                    [0] => best product comment 1
                    [1] => best product comment 2
                    [2] => best product comment 3
                )

        )

)
```